# How to implement ajax in php using functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to build a web app using json, ajax and php to be more clear, I need a php page with different functions that can be called from ajax  method

Eg: phppage.php

```
addmydetails() 
{
   logic goes here
}
```

ajax page

```
/* Get from elements values */
 var values = $(this).serialize();

 $.ajax({
        url: "phppage.php/addmydetails",
        type: "post",
        data: values ,
        success: function (response) {
           // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });
```

So my actual question is that any option to call the function like this in ajax post
**url: "phppage.php/addmydetails"**

Comment: htaccess redirect calls to phppage.php there check whats /addmydetails and execute the function

Comment: Well you can, you post a value to specify which function to use.

Comment: I feel the question is more about `URL re-writing` and its implementation in PHP, this has nothing to do with AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

No need for URL rewriting. Just get the PATH and use call_user_func. Something like this:

In your phppage.php:

```
$method = trim($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], "/");

if(function_exists($method)){
    call_user_func($method);
    exit();
}

function Your_function_name(){
    print "this is my function";
}
```

Then you can access it using this URL --> phppage.php/Your_function_name

Comment: I think OPs question is more on how to access `phppage.php/Your_function_name` as an URL

Comment: isn't it what my answer is? using the code you can access it using phppage.php/Your_function_name

Comment: I think parpar's answer do the trick, kind of very basic url dispatching, lol

Comment: glad to help :D

Comment: Thank you so much parpar for the timely help:)